# Elementary OS6 Stable Fresh install cannot install deb file and no Eddy on AppCenter

Tags: appcenter

[image]

Elementary OS6 Stable Fresh install cannot install deb file and no Eddy on AppCenter, please help?

Comment: Eddy should be available, the developer just got it ported to flatpak

Answer (score -1):

If you decide to stick to this latest eOS crap you can do this:

1. Install `gdebi` with `sudo apt install gdebi` and it won't work out-of-the-box.
2. `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop`
3. Change `Exec=gdebi-gtk %f` to `Exec=sh -c "gdebi-gtk %f"`

Gdebi is far better than AppCenter or Eddy because it will tell you what dependencies are needed for the installation (like the all KDE environment just to get a simple app) and, more importantly, are there gonna be any packages removed as a result of installation which is something that eOS users have experienced.